# Network IP addresses with jq bash command from docker inspect

Tags: json, bash, docker, jq

I want to process `docker inspect <container1> <container2>` out to retrieve via `jq` command exposed ports and IPAddresses assigned to defined networks. So far I've got `jq '{(.[].Name): getpath(path(.[].NetworkSettings.Networks)) | .[].IPAddress}'` which is clearly far from enough.

p.s. I know its easy to write a script that would give such output but I'm curious how to do that using `jq`

**Expected output**

```
{
    # .[].Name
    "/prometheus_prometheus_1": [
        [
            # .[].Config.ExposedPorts
            "9090/tcp"
        ],
        {
            # key   = .[].NetworkSettings.Networks.<index>
            # value = .[].NetworkSettings.Networks[].IPAddress
            "prometheus_internal": "172.21.0.4",
            "system-information": "172.28.0.2"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Input:**

```
[
    {
        "Id": "c2f86bce68441f50f973ae89a835d052e74c083e35b5438f3cec2497bcac79fa",
        "Created": "2018-06-12T05:33:19.811448302Z",
        "Path": "/bin/prometheus",
        "Args": [
            "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml",
            "--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus",
            "--web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries",
            "--web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 13217,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2018-06-12T05:33:20.264845701Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:44a4c1c270dcb5e8caf51e3205fa23343cc903f3823eab53ae204f304d16f62a",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c2f86bce68441f50f973ae89a835d052e74c083e35b5438f3cec2497bcac79fa/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c2f86bce68441f50f973ae89a835d052e74c083e35b5438f3cec2497bcac79fa/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c2f86bce68441f50f973ae89a835d052e74c083e35b5438f3cec2497bcac79fa/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c2f86bce68441f50f973ae89a835d052e74c083e35b5438f3cec2497bcac79fa/c2f86bce68441f50f973ae89a835d052e74c083e35b5438f3cec2497bcac79fa-json.log",
        "Name": "/prometheus_prometheus_1",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "prometheus_prometheus-data:/prometheus:rw",
                "/home/sebastian/projects/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml:rw"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "prometheus_internal",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "always",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "shareable",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/73c16b0735eb15494741e5b821a9df3be8cebb716219ac206d9ee0042e4166ac-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/03c66042305488fea2fe693246e90374743fbb7836ab31e4ee5cdbfbb1c97785/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/80821a00b79334493729e671dfb66cc878aec19fe2d0dfbaf4cde187522b06e8/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f5071cce5513fb3c465ad883297157271ef48c6f59cd88768068224d850c6903/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c9a0cc617abb45fbd4572abb41c7281c96bc9d59c109270c7f1ec7a99f5b055b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5b425f8a440139a8fdcdd7f7fee8189565e9e00304e96f4cfee86ff6b861e068/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e85740d997591d2f60bfa61ea0c82a58636bccaaba970e55f12cf0ff24565c70/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e9c362d971c460b02111122b241888392d77c5b8545ed520c3d74660b16db9b2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5001184fc8ddd25204626f419c1530b970cb37f936a196fb1173f2774310085e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ed2e676f09a4583f2194e752083a7c95be80131f055891dc39f9fed5560f5a73/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/73c16b0735eb15494741e5b821a9df3be8cebb716219ac206d9ee0042e4166ac/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/73c16b0735eb15494741e5b821a9df3be8cebb716219ac206d9ee0042e4166ac/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/73c16b0735eb15494741e5b821a9df3be8cebb716219ac206d9ee0042e4166ac/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "prometheus_prometheus-data",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/prometheus_prometheus-data/_data",
                "Destination": "/prometheus",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/home/sebastian/projects/prometheus/prometheus.yml",
                "Destination": "/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "c2f86bce6844",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "nobody",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "9090/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml",
                "--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus",
                "--web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries",
                "--web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles"
            ],
            "Image": "prom/prometheus:v2.3.0",
            "Volumes": {
                "/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml": {},
                "/prometheus": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/prometheus",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/bin/prometheus"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "b8ff39fd239739ae66051752c1b49b0119862b8f21678fb42400c907d25b1c57",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "prometheus",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "prometheus",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.16.1",
                "maintainer": "The Prometheus Authors <prometheus-developers@googlegroups.com>"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "7be77954d0e6990f565a8526b157236140238cabf0954629598ce3bb9aaae885",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "9090/tcp": null
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/7be77954d0e6",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "prometheus_internal": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "prometheus",
                        "c2f86bce6844"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "145c59986c16003f9a3a30e6b671c34b56225d90243fba88fc295c49b4dcfff6",
                    "EndpointID": "8e3ac8bd4719ea85358c20a8141c37377dd327265916d41ee5d1db6b7496898c",
                    "Gateway": "172.21.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.21.0.4",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:15:00:04",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                },
                "system-information": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "prometheus",
                        "c2f86bce6844"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "f6e67721cb73da7e8d4eacdb709de240014af9af35e66216e6186300c72de330",
                    "EndpointID": "2c31369f8175f2b38a5bc966a8306c8f0f11ac4c264e6ce735d00c87b8a6f44f",
                    "Gateway": "172.28.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.28.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1c:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq '.[] | {(.Name) : [(.Config.ExposedPorts | keys),
                      (.NetworkSettings.Networks | to_entries
                       | map({(.key): .value.IPAddress}) | add)
                     ]
          }' input
```

The output:

```
{
  "/prometheus_prometheus_1": [
    [
      "9090/tcp"
    ],
    {
      "prometheus_internal": "172.21.0.4",
      "system-information": "172.28.0.2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have to remember ``to_entries | map()`` and ``keys``. :) Very very useful. ~Thanks a lot.

Comment: How to store ``jq`` filter? I thought I'm gonna make an alias but it does not work: ``alias jq-dinsp="echo '.[] | {(.Name) : [(.Config.ExposedPorts | keys),(.NetworkSettings.Networks | to_entries | map({(.key): .value.IPAddress}))]}'"``

Comment: @starach, welcome. You are able to store `jq` filter in a separate file, then read that filter from the file, for ex.: `docker inspect <container1> | jq -f jq-dinsp.jq`. The filter file should contain `.[] | {(.Name) : [(.Config.ExposedPorts | keys), (.NetworkSettings.Networks | to_entries | map({(.key): .value.IPAddress}) | add )]}`

Comment: I've set alias for a complete jq command ``alias jq-dinsp="jq '.[] | {(.Name) : [(.Config.ExposedPorts | keys),(.NetworkSettings.Networks | to_entries | map({(.key): .value.IPAddress}))]}'"`` and it works nicely when piping to it. Thanks